# Lead Creation from Web Forms - Upload pdf file into Lead record

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, experience-cloud, web2lead

I have a WordPress form with simple fields: Name, Contact, Email address, Description, and a pdf attachment (all required fields). I want to store the values given by the users as potential leads in my Salesforce org.

I am unsure what are the possible ways by which I can load the pdf file into the Lead record. I know Web-to-Lead does not support pdf files. I understand that this is possible with LWC with Apex (Pro-code) or Experience sites with flows (No-code). I am unsure about the implementation part for the No-Code option though.

Is there some documentation where I can get better help or can anyone guide me with the flow of the process?

Thank you for any kind of advice on the process.

Comment: Maybe you can try following this tutorial here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1197&v=9_THmXR9Fgg&embeds_referring_euri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dweb%2Bto%2Blead%2Busing%2Bflow%26oq%3Dweb%2Bto%2Blead%2Busing%2Bflow%26gs_lcrp%3DEgZjaHJvbWUyCQgAEEUYORigATIHCAEQIRigATI&source_ve_path=MTM5MTE3LDIzODUx&feature=emb_title

but in Salesforce screen flow, now we have a standard file upload input element, hence you don't need any custom coding to build the component. Apart from that, the implementation could be the same, I guess.